# Python recursive function to dump a tree in Excel

Tags: python, django, excel, recursion

I have a very simple directed traversal graph structure in a Django `models.py` file that translates into the following two Python classes :

```
class Node(models.Model):
    position = models.IntegerField() # from 1 to 3
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    value = models.FloatField(default=0.0)

class Edge(models.Model):
    source = models.ForeignKey("Node", related_name="__to")
    destination = models.ForeignKey("Node", related_name="__from")
    weight = models.FloatField(default=0.0)
```

I need to dump the content of that tree into an Excel file. Writing to the Excel document is easy thanks to **xlwt** - I can write to any cell using a simple `write(x, y, content)` function - but I what I'm having difficulties with right now is to go through the entire tree (recursively) and fetching each possible path to write in the Excel file.

Considering I have 3 nodes (A1, A2, A3) in the first position that are each one linked to one node (B1) in the second position which is finally linked to 1 node (C1) in third position, I would need to go through all possible paths and translate that into the following structure in Excel ( is for your understanding but it's actually a separate cell in Excel) :

```
Node A1 in position 1 <links to> Node B1 in position 2 <links to> Node C1 in position 3
Node A2 in position 1 <links to> Node B1 in position 2 <links to> Node C1 in position 3
Node A3 in position 1 <links to> Node B1 in position 2 <links to> Node C1 in position 3
```

In the aforementioned example, I have 5 instances of `Node`, and 5 instances of `Edge`.

In any idea on how I could do that?

Thanks!
J

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, this is a [directed graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_graph) traversal not a directed tree.

A simple algorithm, that ignores the `edges` but based on `position`, and gives the expect output is:

```
>>> positions = [Node.objects.filter(position=i) for i in range(1,3+1)]
>>> import itertools
>>> list(itertools.product(positions))

[(<Node: A1>, <Node: B1>, <Node: C1>),
 (<Node: A2>, <Node: B1>, <Node: C1>),
 (<Node: A3>, <Node: B1>, <Node: C1>)]
```

Comment: Thanks for the heads up - I'm no expert in trees... I mean, graphs. Any idea where I could start looking to solve the original problem?

Comment: Thanks again for your time. Maybe I didn't explain myself clearly enough; what I would need is a way to go through each path, and write the name of each single node used in the specific paths in different cells of an Excel file. In the end, since there are three possible paths, I'd like to have 3 different lines in the Excel document, and 3 columns used for each line/path. Do you see what I mean?

Comment: Your post said that you are comfortable with writing to an Excel, hence I posted the code to perform the traversal.

Comment: Thanks, I understand what you mean. However, in the solution you propose, there is no reference to the `Edge` model, which means that your solution will simply provide a list of all possible combinations of all nodes. What I'd need is to only write down (recursively) the possible paths, i.e. based on `node.__to.all()`. Do you see what I mean?